# PHP nth iteration

Tags: php, loops, iteration, modulus

So I am trying to use PHP to generate some content with the criteria of the nth loop needs to either open or close a div element.  So my goal is to display 8 elements on the page and on the 9th element, I would like to close the div for the 8th element and open a new one for the 9th if there are any more image.  Here is my code.

```
$images; // object
$i = 1;

echo '<div class="outer-container">';

while ( $images->have_images() ) {

     if ( $i === 1 ) {
          echo '<div class="inner-container">';
     }

     echo 'content here';

     if ( $i === 8 || $images->total === $images->current + 1 ) {
          echo '</div><!--.inner-container-->';
     }

     $i++;
}

echo '</div><!--.outer-container-->';
```

End result should look something like this:

```
<div class="outer-container">

<div class="inner-container">
    content here
    content here
    content here
    content here
    content here
    content here
    content here
    content here
</div><!--.inner-container-->

<div class="inner-container">
    content here
    content here
    content here
</div><!--.inner-container-->

</div><!--.outer-container-->
```

I searched around and came to a conclusion that I have to probably use modulus but I am not certain how I can incorporate that into my code.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( $i % 8 == 0) {
      echo '</div><!--.container--><div class="container">';
}
```

Mod operator returns the remainder. You can simply state `$i % 8` or `$i % 8 == 0` or `$i % 8 === 0 as john stated`

But you will need to also open the next div in your conditional depending on how you structure this. An example:

```
<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <?php
        $images; // object
        $i = 1;

        while ( $images->have_images() ) {

             echo 'content here';
             //print_r($i % 8);
             if ( $i % 8 == 0 && $images->total > 8) {
                  echo '</div><!--.inner-container--><div class="inner-container">';
             }

             $i++;
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Added conditional in case your images total happens to be 8 it won't create a rogue empty div.

I'm trying to understand your comment. Are you saying you have an outer container, then an inner container, and inside this inner container you want the loop you defined in the question where each group of 8 is contained in a `container` div?

I added a print r in the loop you can uncomment to verify $i is doing what you want it to. By this code and the fact that $i begins at 1 you should not experience the closing div conditional prematurely.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So does it mean I don't need this at the beginning?      if ( $i === 1 ) {
          echo '<div class="container">';
     }

Comment: yes, the example removed that. No need for the initial $i === 1 condition

Comment: Hmmm it seems to almost work but not quite...I actually have a outer container that surrounds the outside of the while loop but using your code, the container is outside of the outer container...sounds confusing I know, let me update my code with the outer container so you see what I mean.

Comment: So using your code it generates <div class="outer-container"></div><div class="inner-container"></div><div class="inner-container"></div><div class="inner-container"></div>

Comment: See how the outer-container closed before the first inner-container...It should surround the inner-containers.

Comment: I modified the answer but I'm not sure I clearly understood what you want. outer container, inner container and then each group of 8 in their own container class?

Comment: The outer-container doesn't loop, it just surrounds everything in the loop so there is only ONE outer-container.  But for some reason the code I used generates the inner-container OUTSIDE of the outer-container...It's like it closed the outer-container first before it starts the inner-container.

Comment: I just renamed container from the original code to make it clear...

Comment: Please see my end result code up top...

Comment: I updated to match your sample. I ran this locally and it works as expected.

Comment: Do you mind if we jump to chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37489/discussion-between-kai-qing-and-rick)

Answer (score 1):

Modulus is indeed what you're looking for:

```
if ( $i % 8 === 0 ) {
    echo '</div><!--.container-->';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to open a new div

modify the following code:

```
if ( $i === 8 || $images->total === $images->current + 1 ) {
    echo '</div><!--.container-->';
    echo '<div class="container">'; //ADD THIS LINE!!!
}
```

and after you get out of the `while` add the closing `</div>` tag